# How to replay the game and break out of a loop?

Tags: c#

I'm building a program that the dices generates random numbers. I decided to write down in other methods while calling it in the main method. I'm trying to replay the game and break out of the loop by writing in a seperate method. For some reason it won't work and the console shows me an error to which I will show you the picture below.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
        Console.WriteLine("Hey! Welcome to Tina's Dice Game");
        Console.WriteLine("Let's Start!");


        PlayGame();

        PlayAgain();

        RollDice();

        static void PlayGame()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int Dice1 = RollDice();
            int Dice2 = RollDice();



            Console.WriteLine("Dice 1 = " + Dice1);
            Console.WriteLine("Dice 2 = " + Dice2);

            Console.WriteLine("I got " + Dice1 + " and " + Dice2);

            if (Dice1 % 2 == 0 && Dice2 % 2 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Evens are better than odds");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Odds are still cool.");
            }



        }

        


    }
}

        public static void PlayAgain()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play it again? (Yes or No)");
        string answer = Console.ReadLine();

        if (answer == "Yes")
        {
            PlayGame();
        } else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

        public static Random random = new Random();

        public static int RollDice()
        {
        int Dice = random.Next(2, 4);
        return Dice;
        }
```

The console prints out:
[image]

Comment: You can remove the entire `else` statement in `PlayAgain`.  The keywork `break` is used for exiting loops, in this context you would use `return`.

Comment: Personally I think formatting your code will help you understand it better. Try CTRL-K,CTRL-D if you are using visual studio to format it all for example

Answer (score 2):

1. The first issue is with you're not closing your `Main` method.
   Add a closing bracket (`}`) before the `static void PlayGame()` line (and then remove the extraneous bracket after the `PlayGame()` function's definition).
   You might want to reindent your code (that would have made the error glaringly obvious) - there's surely a menu item for that in your IDE.
2. Secondly, you can't use `break` when you're not in a loop; you'd use `return` to "break out" of a function.
3. Thirdly, you have an infinite loop without `break` in your `PlayGame()` method; you'll never get to that `PlayAgain()` call.

Answer (score 0):

I sense that you are learning so here I give you something similar to what you appear to be trying.  I will annotate with comments in the code but here is a basic rundown:

- in the `static void Main()` you output some text first
- Then in my version I create a boolean variable `doIt` and set it to "true" so that I can use that in the loop; looping until it is no longer true - and since I set it to true initially it does one "game" play with `PlayGame();`
- Next I call the PlayAgain method which I changed to return a boolean from your players answer, setting "doIt" to the value: `doIt = PlayAgain();`
- It starts the while loop again and if `doIt` is still true, plays again, otherwise it goes to the next statement (the "Goodbye") then returns exiting the program.

I formatted a bit and here is everything with LONG comments:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hey! Welcome to Tina's Dice Game");
        Console.WriteLine("Let's Start!");
        bool doIt = true;
        while (doIt)
        {
            PlayGame();
            doIt = PlayAgain();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!");
        return;
    }

    // here you had PayGame inside Main() so I left it there
    // the main difference is I now call it ONLY from Main()
    // since the other public methods cannot "see" it
    // this fixes one of the issues
    static void PlayGame()
    {
        bool doingWell = true;
        while (doingWell)
        {
            int dice1 = RollDice();
            int dice2 = RollDice();
            Console.WriteLine("Dice 1 = " + dice1);
            Console.WriteLine("Dice 2 = " + dice2);
            Console.WriteLine("I got " + dice1 + " and " + dice2);
            doingWell = (dice1 % 2 == 0 && dice2 % 2 == 0);
            if (doingWell)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Evens are better than odds");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Odds are still cool.");
            }
        }
    }

    // public method, this returns a boolean from the check:  answer == "Yes"
    // goAgain is set to the true/false value of the condition it checked,
    // returning true only when "Yes" is the answer
    //  Anything else like "YES","yes", "yep", or "no" returns false 
    // since this is a case sensitive comparison
    // reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings
    public static bool PlayAgain()
    {
        Console.Write("Do you want to play it again? (Yes or No)");
        
        string answer;
        answer = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"You said:{answer}");
        var goAgain = answer == "Yes";
        return goAgain;
    }

    // I put the "random" in the roll dice method so we create a new one each time    
    public static int RollDice()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int dice = random.Next(2, 4);
        return dice;
    }
}
```